# where to set DefaultBufferSize in SSIS

Tags: ssis, msbi

To improve performance in transformations implemented using SSIS, there is a note in internet to adjust the DefaultBufferSize value. Where can I find this option settings in the SSIS tool, am unable to locate it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I need to select the transformation and on right side 'Properties' window appears with this option, we can alter it here, Thanks